# Is sending Environment.MahcineName via HttpClient treated as harmful action?

Tags: c#, network-programming

I am logging the download of my application in a very simple way.

```
var deployment = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
if (deployment.IsFirstRun)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.GetAsync("http://mywebsite.net/mywebapi/Log/" + Environment.MachineName);
}
```

Generally I do not get any warnings. But some of my friends reported that their AntiVirus software prevents it from this action.

Is this a malware action for AntiVirus engines? If so, how can this application can get networking permission from the client computer?

Comment: Assuming your app is not for the _intranet_, why not just log the machine's _IP address_?  I doubt the machine name would be of any use to you anyway.  AV software are less likely to block it

Comment: @Micky How can we obtian IP adress of the local network?(Not the client machine).

Comment: "Generally I do not get any warnings" because errors are not observed. Maybe you should log errors and let your friend send you the log.

Comment: @usr well, I misexpressed myself. The problem never bothers the application. The warning directly comes from the AV software. saying that tha application is stealing info from the computer.

Comment: Well, you *are* stealing the machine name :) That's a privacy issue. You can of course circumvent that by encrypting it.

Comment: I tried something like this a long time ago with no problems. Have you tried wrapping it in another object before appending it to the url ?

Comment: Try this: `string machine = Environment.MachineName; client.GetAsync(url + machine); `

Comment: @JalalMostafa I, first, tried your solution an it worked, as well.

Comment: Awesome! I will post it as an answer too!

Comment: @JalalMostafa As a convention, I will upvote that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encrypt the value so that the AV software cannot see it. Right now it seems to be detected as information theft which it in fact is. I would not want software to transmit my machine name which contains my first name.